# How to implement a thread-safe counter at database level?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, jpa

I have a table named "stats" which has only one row for statistics. I want to update "totalProductCount" column of this table when a new product registered.(Increase totalProductCount by one when a new product is registered)

Problem is my application's register module is multithreaded and I think race condition is occured when I call this method from different threads. Is there any way to increase a column value from different threads?

```
public void increaseProductCount(long reqId) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("update stats set total_product_count = total_product_count + 1 where id = 1");
    query.executeUpdate();

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: What problems you see with this code and multiple threads? The value will be the same after 10 concurrent threads, as the database will (depending on your settings) make them wait until previous updates are committed. Is your product registration also part of this database? if it isn't, and all you are looking for is a database counter, you might want to look into sequence objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually encountered instances of the race condition?

All `UPDATE` statements are atomic and acquire write locks on the updated data. As long as you're using at least `READ COMMITED` isolation level (which you would be ill advised not to anyway), you should be fine.